# Crear un arreglo en Laravel para rellenar una gráfica

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes estoy intentando primero de todo construir un arreglo, pero vaya estoy fallando hasta en eso. Quiero sacar un arreglo con dos tablas relacionadas:

**Mi tabla `tecnologias`** (son equipos vendidos)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre equipo |
| 2 | nombre equipo |

**Mi tabla `equipos`**

| id | tecnologia_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

La idea es sacar un arreglo donde me muestre los equipos vendidos y haciendo un `count` para saber cuantos se han vendido de cada uno, y además sacar el nombre que esta en la tabla `tecnologias`.

Entonces en la gráfica de charts.js quiero hacerla con bars, entonces debajo que me salgan los nombres de las tecnologias(solo las que han sido vendidas) y en los resultados de cada tecnología el `count` asociado a cada tecnología.

Espero haberme explicado bien, como decia estoy probando simplemente a construir el arreglo pero sin éxito:

**Esto tengo en mi controlador**

```
$resultado = [];
        $tecnologias = Tecnologia::join('equipos', 'tecnologias.id', '=', 'equipos.tecnologia_id')->get();
        $data = Equipo::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, tecnologia_id'))->groupBy('tecnologia_id')->get();
        foreach($tecnologias as $j){
            $resultado[$j->tecnologia_id];
        }
        dd($resultado)
```

**Lo que quiero es esto:**

```
array:12 [▼
  "nombre equipo 1" => 4
  "nombre equipo 2" => 1
  "nombre equipo 3" => 5
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar tu consulta de esta manera:

```
Tecnología::selectRaw('name, COUNT(tecnologia_id) AS Total')
          ->join('equipos', 'tecnologias.id', '=', 'equipos.tecnologia_id')
          ->groupBy('name')
          ->get()
          ->toArray();
```

Ya que:

- La intención es obtener un solo conjunto de datos
- Limitamos en el mismo [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods) las columnas requeridas
- El agrupamiento debe ser por la columna no calculada, en este caso `name`
- En lugar de solo obtener al final la colección, usamos el método toArray para pasar la colección a un *array de PHP*

Lo anterior te debería dar una salida similar a esta:

```
[
    [
        "equipo" => "Equipo1",
        "Total" => 12,
    ],
    [
        "equipo" => "Equipo2",
        "Total" => 13,
    ],
    ............
]
```

Ya el resto solo será iterar...

Comment: Nada ya tengo la duda solucionada, dado que la respuesta esta bien respondida voy a marcarla! Gracias @BetaM